# Piping awk's print/printf output into a shell command makes that statement run after all other unrelated print/printf statements

Tags: awk, pipe

Given this `awk` script:

```
END  {
print "Y" | "cat" 

print "X"
print "X"
}

# Output: 
# X
# X
# Y
```

Why isn't Y printed first given that it's supposed to run before the other statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the `cat` process to terminate (and the `Y` to be printed) before the `X`s, then just call `close("cat")` after the `print "Y" | "cat"`.

All the rest is explained in the manpage, which you better read.

> Why isn't Y printed first given that it's supposed to run before the other statements?

The `cat` is not supposed to write its output and terminate before the other statements. It may write its output before, after or in between your two `print "X"` calls.

When you use something like `print ... | "command ..."` in awk, `command ..` is started as an asynchronous process with its stdin connected to a pipe (via  `popen("command ...", "w")`), and that process will not necessarily terminate and write its output before you call `close("command ...")` (or that is implicitly done when awk terminates).

See an example like:

```
BEGIN {
   print "foo" | "cat > file"
   print "bar" | "cat > file"
}
```

The result will be that `file` will contain both lines, `foo` and `bar`; the `cat > file` command will not be run separately for each line.

Comment: I will read the manpage, but it would be nice if you could provide a simple explanation as to why I must `close("cat")` first to have `Y` printed before the `X`s

Comment: `close(cmd)` does actually call C's `pclose(cmd)` and like `pclose()`, waits for the process in which `cmd` was run and returns its exit status. Hence the guarantee that `cat` will have finished by the time `close()` returns.

Comment: @ilkkachu `close("cat")` does wait for it, as Stéphane Chazelas has already mentioned -- because it's calling `pclose(3)`. This is **not** an implementation detail, the POSIX standard *requires* awk to implement pipelines with popen/pclose (or with other functions which *exactly* like them)

Comment: @user414777, ahh, thanks, it seems I didn't register that, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Redirections and pipes in awk are similar to redirections and pipes in sh, but there is one major difference. In sh, `foo >bar` keeps `bar` open only for the duration of the `foo` command, and `foo | bar` waits for both `foo` and `bar` to terminate. In awk, a redirection or pipe remains open until it's closed explicitly, and redirecting or piping to the same file name or command multiple times reuses the open redirection/pipe.

For example, in sh, this prints `a`, `b`, `c`, `a`, `b`, because each sort command gets just two lines of input:

```sh
{ echo b; echo a; } | sort
echo c
{ echo b; echo a; } | sort
```

But in awk, this prints `c`, `a`, `a`, `b`, `b` (assuming that awk's output is line-buffered, otherwise `c` could be delayed) because there is a single `sort` command and it won't print anything until it has all of its input data, which only happens when the input side of the pipe gets closed.

```awk
{ print "b"; print "a"; } | "sort";
print "c";
{ print "b"; print "a"; } | "sort";
```

To make a piped command terminate, call the `close` function explicitly. Awk implicitly closes all open pipes and redirections when it exits. This prints `a`, `b`, `c`, `a`, `b`:

```awk
{ print "b"; print "a"; } | "sort"; close("sort");
print "c";
{ print "b"; print "a"; } | "sort"; close("sort");
```

Likewise, this awk snippet creates a two-line file, since `foo` is opened once by the first line and is still open when the second line runs:

```awk
print "hello" >"foo";
print "world" >"foo";
```

Whereas this sh snippet creates a one-line file, because the second line opens the file that was created by the first line and truncates it before writing `world`:

```sh
echo hello >foo
echo world >foo
```

The main reason awk is designed this way is that there's an implicit loop around the processing of each line. In sh, if you want to process lines in a loop, you'd typically write the redirection around the loop:

```sh
while read line; do
  if condition "$line"; then
    process line
  fi
done >output
```

But in awk, there would be no way to apply the redirection to the implicit loop, so you write

```
condition($0) { process $0 >"output" }
```

The awk way is also more powerful because you can open and close pipes at will, even in the middle of a loop or other blocks. In sh, this is possible for redirections with the `exec` builtin, but not for pipes: a pipe has to be applied to a (possibly compound) command as a whole.